# ios How to save NSData represeting a video to camera roll?

Tags: ios, video, camera, save, nsdata

I have an NSData object that contains video data. I would like to save it to the Camera Roll. How can i accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: This might answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290385/how-can-i-write-a-nsdata-file-as-video-in-to-photolibrary-savedphotosalbum

Comment: I can't seem to get the NSdata part from that post